# Is it possible to install Open Source Chef Server on Suse Enterprise Linux 11 SP3?

Tags: chef-infra, suse

from http://docs.getchef.com/chef_system_requirements.html I understand that the requirements for Open Source Chef Server are either "Enterprise Linux (e.g. Red Hat Enterprise Linux, CentOS)" or "Ubuntu".

But looking here https://build.opensuse.org/project/show?project=systemsmanagement%3Achef%3Amaster and here https://build.opensuse.org/project/show?project=systemsmanagement%3Achef%3A10 it seems that Suse is providing packages for Chef which to me seem to include Chef Server - even though only the package containing Chef 10 is stable right now.

Has anyone installed Chef Server on Suse?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is not supported by the Omnibus Chef-server packages, so this not recommended. You could build your own packages or trying using the distro ones but you won't find nearly as much help from SO/IRC/etc.